# Is there a phrase for "I cast a glance" but as in an accident?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, word-usage, synonyms

I want to say

> *"I accidentally cast a glance at my watch... shoot!  It's 10:30"*

except I don't want to use the word "accidentally" (or cast for that matter...). Is there a way to maybe combine them with a word that encompasses both, an unintentional seeing of the time?

Comment: My gaze fell on my watch... Shoot!  It's 10:30.

Comment: I inadvertently glanced towards my watch?

Comment: I happened to glance at my watch?

Comment: By the way, does this question not belong on [Writers](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions)? I'm not sure where the boundaries lie.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My first thought was that you might ***glimpse*** your watch:

> ***[glimpse](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/glimpse)***
>
> **VERB**
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> 1. See or perceive briefly or partially.
>
>    *‘he glimpsed a figure standing in the shade’*

(from the Oxford Dictionaries)

But then I felt that wasn't quite right.  What you really did was ***catch sight of*** your watch:

> ***[catch (or get a) sight of](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/sight)***
>
> Glimpse for a moment; suddenly notice.
>
> *‘when she caught sight of him she smiled’*

So in your sentence, it would be:

> *I **caught sight of** my watch... shoot! It's 10:30!*

An anonymous user (thanks, whoever you are!) noticed that the Oxford Dictionaries' definition of ***glimpse*** as a noun offers yet another option via its sample sentence:

> ***[glimpse](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/glimpse)***
>
> **NOUN**
>
> 1. A momentary or partial view.
>
>    *‘she caught a glimpse of the ocean’*

The anonymous user noted that

> _this may arguably imply even less intent than to "catch sight," since the latter can sometimes apply to an object one is specifically seeking.-

So perhaps the best option would be:

> *I **caught a glimpse of** my watch... shoot! It's 10:30!*

(I'm embarrassed that I didn't put the two together myself!)

Answer (score 7):

One way to do this would be to take yourself out of the subject position. You can make yourself the passive victim of your watch's attention-getting machinations by using the expression [***catch someone's eye***](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/catch-someone-s-eye). From MacMillan Dictionary:

> if something catches your eye, you suddenly notice it
>   *There was one painting that caught my eye.*

So in your example, you were just minding your own business, not meaning to check the time at all, when suddenly

> My watch **caught my eye**...shoot! It's 10:30!

Answer (score 6):

If you didn't *intend* to look, then you probably wouldn't describe what happened with that verb. (Even if that's what happened.)

You could use one of the following phrases instead:

> I became aware of the time.
>   I suddenly realized the time.
>   I noticed the time on my watch.

Answer (score 4):

How about: "My eye strayed to my watch."

Answer (score -1):

Remarked.
I remarked the hands on my wristwatch - shoot 10:30!

Comment: Welcome to ELU, please elaborate why you think this is the best answer.

Comment: Or even why you believe that it is *an* answer at all.